# F structure of an algebraic set (why is this ring hom injective?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the notion of the field of definition of an algebraic set. Specifically, I'm stuck on page 6 of the book *Linear Algebraic Groups* by TA Springer.

Suppose $F \subset K$ is a field extension and $X \subset K^n$ is the zero set of polynomials $\{f_i\}$ in $F[T]$. Let $I_F$ (resp $I_K$) be the ideal generated by the set $\{f_i\}$ in $F[T]$ (resp $K[T]$).  We have an injective $F$-algebra homomorphism

$$F[T]/I_F \rightarrow K[T]/I_K$$

Springer claims that this induces an isomorphism given by multiplication:

$$K \otimes _F F[T]/I_F \rightarrow K[T]/I_K$$

I don't see why this should be injective.  More precisely, this map should be given by

$$K \otimes _F F[T]/I_F \rightarrow K \otimes _F K[T]/I_K \rightarrow K[T]/I_K$$

The left map is injective since $K$ is a free $F$ module, and I can see that the composition is surjective, but I don't know why the composition should be injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't factor the maps like that-- if you do the second map will often not be injective (for instance take $I_F = I_K = 0$, $F = \mathbb Q$, $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$).

Instead take the map $K[T]/I_K \to K \otimes_F F[T]/I_F$, given by $\sum k_i T^i \mapsto \sum k_i \otimes ( T^i + I_F)$, and show that this is an explicit inverse.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to think for a minute

Comment: ah, and that inverse is well defined precisely because $I_K$ is generated as a $K[T]$ ideal by elements of $F[T]$